# Linking unknown list of outs to cc_library

Tags: build, bazel

I have a `genrule` that takes "in" a config file, and spits "out" a large number of built files (`*.so*`s and `*.h` files):

```
genrule(
    name = "ros_auto",
    local = True,
    srcs = [":package_list"],
    outs = ["ros_built.tgz"],
    tools = [":build_packages.bash"],
    cmd = "$(location :build_packages.bash) $< $@"
    )
```

Next up I need to take all of the files that are output from the above `genrule`, and create a `cc_library` from them like below (at the moment the only manageable way I can find to register the output files in the `genrule` is tarballing them & declaring the tar):

```
cc_library(
    name = "ros",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/**/*.h",
        "include/**/*.hpp",
        ]),
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    )
```

No matter where I look I seem to continue to find deadend after deadend (`http_archive` uses a `download_and_extract` method which assumes the `*tgz` is remote, the `cc_library` implementation is inaccessible / unextendible Java, etc.).

I would've thought the problem of *"I have node A that generates a tonne of outfiles, which node B depends on"* would be extremely common and have a simple solution. Am I missing something obvious?

**Context:**

I have this working with a local repository rule that takes in the local directory, and uses the `cc_library` rule above as the build_file parameter (but that means building the first step of this process has to be done completely outside of the Bazel build process which is not how this should be done):

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "ros",
    path = "/tmp/ros_debug",
    build_file = "//ros:BUILD.bazel",
    licenses = ["https://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/licenses.html"]
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic bazel philosophie is that a build should depend on unambigious inputs/dependencies and outputs strictly defined files in order to guarantee reproducable builds. Having a genrule generating a "random" number of files that a target should depend on is against this philosophy. Thats why you cant find a good way to achieve this.

A way to work around this is to have a single `outs` file in your genrule where you write down the names of the generated files (or a log of your script or whatever). Then you can define an additional filegroup containing all the generated files, using `glob`. Then add your genrule as dependency to the rule of node B and the filegroup to the `srcs`. Therefore it is guaranteed, that the files are generated before building the node B

Comment: Hi, i realize that  this is a bit late in time, but i am stuck with a similar problem and I was wondering: how can you "define an additional filegroup containing all the generated files, using glob" ?  in the documentation (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#glob): "Since glob() runs during BUILD file evaluation, glob() matches files only in your source tree, never generated files."